# Re-direct query not working

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is supposed to redirect the user to the index file if the user ($uid) has submitted an entry in the last hour.  It's not working.

Any idea why not?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$queryuidcount = "select loginid from submission where datesubmitted > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hours) AND loginid = '$uid'"; 
$uidresult = mysql_query($queryuidcount);

if (mysql_num_rows($uidresult) >= 1)
{

   session_write_close();
   header("Location:http://www.domain.com/sample/index.php");
   exit;

}
```

Comment: the redirect seems ok. what is the result of $uidresult?

Comment: Have tried setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and checking for whitespace before calling `header()`?  Checking `headers_sent()` can also help.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there should be a space between `Location:` and `http://someurl`, otherwise it's not a correctly formed HTTP header (some browsers can cope, some choke on it):

```
Location: http://someurl
```

Second, are you getting a "headers already sent" warning? That would mean you already started output before this line (e.g. whitespace at file beginning, UTF BOM marks, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have forgot to put `session_start()` on top of  your script since you are using a sessio related function below. Also, no need to specify whole domain path, just the file name should be fine:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

If there is any error, you can know about it by putting these lines on top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also make sure that some records are returned:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($uidresult) >= 1)
{
   exit('found rows !!');
}
```

Comment: 'Also, no need to specify whole domain path, just the file name should be fine:'  This is WRONG.  Although most browsers accept it and do as intended, this is against the specs - RFC2616.

Answer (score 0):

Does the code even reach the code inside the if-statement? try a 
`var_dump("foo");` 
there, because I reckon the header looks good. 
It could be that the exit; is interfering with the redirect though.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL code doesn't seem correct. Change the hours to hour instead.

```
(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

Perhaps you could you use TIMEDIFF instead?

```
mysql> select TIMEDIFF('2010-07-07 09:38:28',NOW()); 
+---------------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF('2010-07-07 09:38:28',NOW()) |
+---------------------------------------+
| -01:03:38                             |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```